# Get a complete dependency graph in maven

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

I have a problem with maven dependencies. I try in my maven plugin to have a full dependencies graph, but some duplicated nodes does not appear.

My maven project is made of :

- "dependency_test", the parent project of 4 modules
- "mod1", "mod2", "mod3", "mod4", the child modules
- "dependency_test_maven_plugin", the maven plugin project

here are the differents pom.xml files :

dependency_test :

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.aned.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>dependency_test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <modules>
        <module>mod1</module>
        <module>mod2</module>
        <module>mod3</module>
    </modules>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.aned.test</groupId>
                <artifactId>mod1</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.aned.test</groupId>
                <artifactId>mod2</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.aned.test</groupId>
                <artifactId>mod3</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.aned.test</groupId>
                <artifactId>mod4</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.aned</groupId>
            <artifactId>dependency_test_maven_plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

mod1 :

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.aned.test</groupId>
        <artifactId>dependency_test</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>mod1</artifactId>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.aned.test</groupId>
            <artifactId>mod2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.aned.test</groupId>
            <artifactId>mod3</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.aned</groupId>
                <artifactId>dependency_test_maven_plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>dependency-test-goal</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

mod2 :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.aned.test</groupId>
        <artifactId>dependency_test</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>mod2</artifactId>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.aned.test</groupId>
            <artifactId>mod3</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.aned.test</groupId>
            <artifactId>mod4</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

mod3 :

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>com.aned.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>dependency_test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
  </parent>
  <artifactId>mod3</artifactId>
</project>
```

mod4 :

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>com.aned.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>dependency_test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
  </parent>
  <artifactId>mod4</artifactId>
</project>
```

My dependency graph is so like :

```
mod1
--mod2
----mod3
----mod4
--mod3
```

I need to have this complete graph in my "dependency_test_maven_plugin" plugin. For now, it look like :

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.aned</groupId>
    <artifactId>dependency_test_maven_plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>maven-plugin</packaging>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-plugin-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugin-tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-plugin-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-project</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.shared</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-tree</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Mojo class :

```
package dependency_test_maven_plugin;

import java.util.Arrays;

import org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.filter.ArtifactFilter;
import org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.filter.ExcludesArtifactFilter;
import org.apache.maven.execution.MavenSession;
import org.apache.maven.plugin.AbstractMojo;
import org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException;
import org.apache.maven.plugins.annotations.Component;
import org.apache.maven.plugins.annotations.LifecyclePhase;
import org.apache.maven.plugins.annotations.Mojo;
import org.apache.maven.plugins.annotations.Parameter;
import org.apache.maven.plugins.annotations.ResolutionScope;
import org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuildingRequest;
import org.apache.maven.project.MavenProject;
import org.apache.maven.project.ProjectBuildingRequest;
import org.apache.maven.shared.dependency.graph.DependencyGraphBuilder;
import org.apache.maven.shared.dependency.graph.DependencyGraphBuilderException;
import org.apache.maven.shared.dependency.graph.DependencyNode;
import org.apache.maven.shared.dependency.graph.traversal.CollectingDependencyNodeVisitor;

@Mojo(name = "dependency-test-goal", defaultPhase = LifecyclePhase.PROCESS_RESOURCES, requiresDependencyCollection = ResolutionScope.COMPILE_PLUS_RUNTIME, requiresDependencyResolution = ResolutionScope.COMPILE_PLUS_RUNTIME)
public class JLinkMojo extends AbstractMojo {

    @Parameter(defaultValue = "${project}", readonly = true, required = true)
    MavenProject project;

    @Parameter(defaultValue = "${session}", readonly = true, required = true)
    private MavenSession session;

    @Component(hint = "default")
    private DependencyGraphBuilder dependencyGraphBuilder;

    ArtifactFilter artifactFilter;
    ProjectBuildingRequest buildingRequest;

    public void execute() throws MojoExecutionException {
        artifactFilter = new ExcludesArtifactFilter(Arrays.asList("com.aned:dependency_test_maven_plugin"));
        buildingRequest = new DefaultProjectBuildingRequest(session.getProjectBuildingRequest());

        buildingRequest.setProject(project);

        try {
            DependencyNode rootNode = dependencyGraphBuilder.buildDependencyGraph(buildingRequest, artifactFilter);
            getLog().info("Start depdendency graph");
            int level = 0;
            displayNode(rootNode, level);
            getLog().info("End depdendency graph");

            CollectingDependencyNodeVisitor visitor = new CollectingDependencyNodeVisitor();
            rootNode.accept(visitor);

            for (DependencyNode dependencyNode : visitor.getNodes()) {
                getLog().info("Start depdendency graph for node " + dependencyNode.getArtifact().getArtifactId());
                displayNode(dependencyNode, level);
                getLog().info("End depdendency graph for node " + dependencyNode.getArtifact().getArtifactId());
            }

        } catch (DependencyGraphBuilderException e) {
            throw new MojoExecutionException("Error", e);
        }
    }

    private void displayNode(DependencyNode rootNode, int level) {
        String indentation = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < level; i++) {
            indentation += "--";
        }
        getLog().info(indentation + rootNode.getArtifact().getArtifactId());

        for (DependencyNode childrenNode : rootNode.getChildren()) {
            displayNode(childrenNode, level + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

On execution, the mojo traces are :

```
[INFO] --- dependency_test_maven_plugin:1.0.0:dependency-test-goal (default) @ mod1 ---
[INFO] Start depdendency graph
[INFO] mod1
[INFO] --mod2
[INFO] ----mod4
[INFO] --mod3
[INFO] End depdendency graph
[INFO] Start depdendency graph for node mod1
[INFO] mod1
[INFO] --mod2
[INFO] ----mod4
[INFO] --mod3
[INFO] End depdendency graph for node mod1
[INFO] Start depdendency graph for node mod2
[INFO] mod2
[INFO] --mod4
[INFO] End depdendency graph for node mod2
[INFO] Start depdendency graph for node mod4
[INFO] mod4
[INFO] End depdendency graph for node mod4
[INFO] Start depdendency graph for node mod3
[INFO] mod3
[INFO] End depdendency graph for node mod3
```

So, in the dependency graph traces like in visitor.getNodes traces, the dependency from mod2 to mod3 is not visible (I think it's because it's a duplicate of the link from mod1 to mod3).
Is there a way to have the complete trace :

```
mod1
--mod2
----mod3
----mod4
--mod3
```

Edit 1 : If I try to use dependency:tree on my parent project, I got the same result :

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ mod1 ---
[INFO] com.aned.test:mod1:jar:1.0.0
[INFO] +- com.aned.test:mod2:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.aned.test:mod4:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.aned.test:mod3:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] \- com.aned:dependency_test_maven_plugin:jar:1.0.0:provided
[INFO]    +- org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:3.6.0:provided
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-model:jar:3.6.0:provided
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:jar:3.6.0:provided
[INFO]    |  +- org.eclipse.sisu:org.eclipse.sisu.plexus:jar:0.3.3:provided
[INFO]    |  |  \- javax.enterprise:cdi-api:jar:1.0:provided
[INFO]    |  |     \- javax.annotation:jsr250-api:jar:1.0:provided
[INFO]    |  +- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:3.1.0:provided
[INFO]    |  \- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-classworlds:jar:2.5.2:provided
[INFO]    +- org.apache.maven:maven-project:jar:2.2.1:provided
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-settings:jar:2.2.1:provided
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-profile:jar:2.2.1:provided
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-artifact-manager:jar:2.2.1:provided
[INFO]    |  |  +- org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-provider-api:jar:1.0-beta-6:provided
[INFO]    |  |  \- backport-util-concurrent:backport-util-concurrent:jar:3.1:provided
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-registry:jar:2.2.1:provided
[INFO]    |  +- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interpolation:jar:1.11:provided
[INFO]    |  \- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-container-default:jar:1.0-alpha-9-stable-1:provided
[INFO]    |     +- junit:junit:jar:3.8.1:provided
[INFO]    |     \- classworlds:classworlds:jar:1.1-alpha-2:provided
[INFO]    +- org.apache.maven:maven-core:jar:3.6.0:provided
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-settings-builder:jar:3.6.0:provided
[INFO]    |  |  \- org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-sec-dispatcher:jar:1.4:provided
[INFO]    |  |     \- org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-cipher:jar:1.4:provided
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-builder-support:jar:3.6.0:provided
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-repository-metadata:jar:3.6.0:provided
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-model-builder:jar:3.6.0:provided
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-resolver-provider:jar:3.6.0:provided
[INFO]    |  |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.25:provided
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.maven.resolver:maven-resolver-impl:jar:1.3.1:provided
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.maven.resolver:maven-resolver-api:jar:1.3.1:provided
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.maven.resolver:maven-resolver-spi:jar:1.3.1:provided
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.maven.resolver:maven-resolver-util:jar:1.3.1:provided
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.maven.shared:maven-shared-utils:jar:3.2.1:provided
[INFO]    |  |  \- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.5:provided
[INFO]    |  +- org.eclipse.sisu:org.eclipse.sisu.inject:jar:0.3.3:provided
[INFO]    |  +- com.google.inject:guice:jar:no_aop:4.2.1:provided
[INFO]    |  |  +- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:provided
[INFO]    |  |  \- com.google.guava:guava:jar:25.1-android:provided
[INFO]    |  |     +- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:3.0.2:provided
[INFO]    |  |     +- org.checkerframework:checker-compat-qual:jar:2.0.0:provided
[INFO]    |  |     +- com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:jar:2.1.3:provided
[INFO]    |  |     +- com.google.j2objc:j2objc-annotations:jar:1.1:provided
[INFO]    |  |     \- org.codehaus.mojo:animal-sniffer-annotations:jar:1.14:provided
[INFO]    |  +- javax.inject:javax.inject:jar:1:provided
[INFO]    |  +- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-component-annotations:jar:1.7.1:provided
[INFO]    |  \- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.8.1:provided
[INFO]    \- org.apache.maven.shared:maven-dependency-tree:jar:3.0.1:provided
[INFO]       \- org.eclipse.aether:aether-util:jar:0.9.0.M2:provided
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] dependency_test 1.0.0 .............................. SUCCESS [  3.769 s]
[INFO] mod3 ............................................... SUCCESS [  0.153 s]
[INFO] mod2 ............................................... SUCCESS [  0.110 s]
[INFO] mod1 1.0.0 ......................................... SUCCESS [  0.097 s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Thank you,

Comment: Have you tried to run `mvn dependency:tree` command? It might help

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I edit the question with the dependency:tree result (same issue, unfortunally...)

Comment: Did you try Maven dependency tree with output appended? It allows to aggregate the dependency trees of each module. `mvn dependency:tree -DappendOutput -DoutputFile=/path/to/dependencyTree.txt`

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but you can see all dependencies (including duplicated) using:

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose
```

Answer (score 0):

What's happening: "mod3" resolves to the nearest parent.

I believe this falls under "dependency mediation" although that is more for version resolution.

To get the tree you expect you would have to buildDependencyGraph with the children as the root.